# Reference appear twice in my Navigation bar (beamer/latex)

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

In my navigation bar I have two reference titles?

I use the following code:

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}

\usetheme[
    menuwidth={0.3\paperwidth},%
    url={web}
    ]{p}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}

\newcommand{\semitransp}[2][35]{\color{fg!#1}#2}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[round, sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}


\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,automata,shapes,shadows,trees}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\presetkeys{bclogo}{
ombre=true,
epBord=3,
couleur = blue!15!white,
couleurBord = red,
arrondi = 0.2,
logo=\bctrombone
}{}

\definecolor{RawSienna}{cmyk}{0,0.72,1,0.45} 
\definecolor{Magenta}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{7.2}\selectfont}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}% Rule colour
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\wd0+13pt}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=mycolor,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
      left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,boxsep=0pt,width=\@tempdima]
    #1
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
(\cite{peterson1996fatal}).
(\cite{fournier1999functional})
(\cite{zhu2010constrained})
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\begin{frame}
(\cite{copty2005path})
(\cite{hunt2002introduction})
(\cite{copty2005path})
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \footnotesize
%        \tiny
        \bibliographystyle{agsm}%apalike}%IEEEtran} %acm
        \bibliography{my DB}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Can you help me ?
[image: Refeerance page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange. Can you please show us a complete MWE instead of code fragments? [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Since your code evidently does not use `biblatex` (you use `natbib` instead), I have retagged your question. You will make it easier for us to answer your question if you can give [a full compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows the undesirable behaviour instead of just a short snippet that we have to complete.

Comment: @user2320492 I tried your example and do not get the duplicate entry. However as I do not have your beamer theme, I replaced this line with a default theme. So you might want to look into the theme you use.

Comment: I used \usetheme{Warsaw} and still get the same error.

Comment: When the reference is empty (?) it shows one time but when it get recognized it, it appears two.

Answer (score 2):

The error on adding this line:

```
\section*{References}
```

The section is created automatically by the bibliography